# Is there a way to refresh the task list in VSCode?

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

The first time I open VSCode, it scans my gulpfile and populates the task list. However, if I add a new task to my gulpfile, and then Run Task, it will only show the initially loaded tasks. Is there a way to manually refresh the task list? Right now I've resorted to restarting VSCode everytime I need to run a new task.

Comment: I have logged this as issue on our end to look into.

Comment: @BenjaminPasero Any updates on this? It seems Code reloads my tasks... sometimes.  I can't find a pattern to it, and reloading the window, as the answer below suggests, seems to be the most consistent way around this.

Comment: No, but maybe add your comment to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9849

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not a very convenient way of reloading - but try Command Palette -> Reload Window instead of restarting VSCode.

Comment: yes, pressing 'Refresh Project Tasks' doesn't work, this did!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than reloading the entire window, you can edit (or create) /.vscode/tasks.json, which will trigger a refresh on all tasks in your gulpfile.js.

Adding or removing a blank line will count as an edit for purposes of refreshing your task list, so this seems faster and more efficient than reloading the window or opening/closing the IDE.

Comment: Adding and then removing a single space, then saving was enough to trigger it for me.  Thanks.